# Highstock points don't align with tick correctly

Tags: highcharts

I tried to make a line chart with highstock but I got a problem with aligning points with ticks on X-axis.
[image: Align Problem]

Here are some of my code snippets for the chart.

```
 jQuery('#chart-area').highcharts('StockChart', {

                    xAxis: {
                        minRange: 7 * 24 * 3600000,
                        minTickInterval: 24 * 3600000

                    },
                    rangeSelector: {
                        inputEnabled: true,
                        selected: 1,
                        buttons: [
                            {
                                type: 'week',
                                count: 1,
                                text: '1w'
                            },
                            {
                                type: 'week',
                                count: 2,
                                text: '2w'
                            },
                            {
                                type: 'month',
                                count: 1,
                                text: '1m'
                            },
                            {
                                type: 'month',
                                count: 2,
                                text: '2m'
                            },
                            {
                                type: 'month',
                                count: 3,
                                text: '3m'
                            },
                            {
                                type: 'month',
                                count: 6,
                                text: '6m'
                            }
                        ]
                    },

                    title: {
                        text: 'Test Execution Trend'
                    },

                    subtitle: {
                        text: $scope.currentStream
                    },


                    series: [
                        {
                            name: 'Test Success Percentage',
                            pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
                            data: $scope.data,

                            marker: {
                                enabled: true,
                                radius: 3
                            },
                            shadow: true,
                            tooltip: {
                                valueDecimals: 0
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            );
        });
    }
```

I don't even know why this could happen. Is there any problems in my codes?

Here is jsfiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/U85D6/

Comment: You need to show us what is in your data ($scope.data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your data isn't starting at specific day, but it's about 16:00. Highcharts ticks are placed at 00:00. That example should explain you better:  http://jsfiddle.net/U85D6/1/

I have addeed

```
    tooltip: {
        xDateFormat: '%A, %b %e, %H:%M'
    },
```

to show full date for points.